# NoLock queries on SQl server with Breeze Queries

Tags: breeze

Is there any way in which I can modify all, or a specific Breeze query, to query with NoLock on?

So far I have tried two approaches.

The first approach consisted of deriving from BreezeConfig - similar to 
https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/_Internal/Sample_WebApi/Controllers/BreezeConfig.cs

then overriding GetTransactionSettings as follows, hoping that all queries will now be wrapped by transactions.

```
    public override TransactionSettings GetTransactionSettings()
    {
        var settings = base.GetTransactionSettings();
        settings.TransactionType = TransactionType.TransactionScope;
        settings.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
        return settings;
    }
```

Sql profiler shows me that my reads aren't wrapped in transactions :/

The second approach I tried is to modify EFContextProvider's behaviour. This failed - the only hooks I can find, even if I derive, are for modifying save-changes. Nothing for read-only behaviour.

Im still investigating Jay's suggestion. But I probably have no idea what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the EFContextProvider then I don't think so because Entity Framework doesn't provide this capability.

However you can intercept the transaction processing on the server to accomplish something similar.

Take a look at this post: [Entity Framework with NOLOCK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926656/entity-framework-with-nolock)

Comment: see my modified question above.