# Is there a way to reference a SQL statement to the C# EF code which generated the SQL?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, debugging

When I troubleshoot a large .NET app which uses only stored procedures, I capture the sql which includes the SP name from SQL Server Profiler and then it's easy to do a global search for the SP in the source files and find the exact line which produced the SQL.

When using Entity Framework, this is not possible due to the dynamic creation of SQL statements. However there are times when I capture some problematic sql statements from production and want to know where in the code they were generated from.

I know one can have EF generate logs and tracing on demand. This probably would be taxing for a busy server and produces too much logs. I read some stuff about using mini profiler but not sure if it fits my needs as I don't have access to the production server. I do however have access to attach SQL Server Profiler to the database server.

My idea is to find a way to have EF attach/inject a unique code to the generated SQL but it doesn't affect the outcome of the SQL. I can then use it to cross reference it to the line of code which injected it into the SQL. The unique code is static which means a unique static code is used for every EF linq statement. Maybe sent as a dummy sql or a comment along with the sql statement. 
I know this will add some extra traffic but in my case, it will add extra flexibility and cut a lot of troubleshooting time.

Any ideas of how to do this or any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

One very simple approach would be to execute something via `ExecuteStoreCommand()`: [Refresh data from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615535/refresh-data-from-stored-procedure/26717601#26717601). I'm not sure if you can "execute" just a comment, but at the very least you should be able to do something like:

```cs
ExecuteStoreCommand("DECLARE @MyTag VARCHAR(100) = 'some_unique_id';");
```

This is very simple, but you would have to find the association in two steps:

1. Get the SessionID (i.e. SPID) from poorly performing query in SQL Server Profiler
2. Search the Profiler entries for the prior SQL statement for that same SPID

Another option that might be a little more complicated but would remove that additional step when it comes to making that association is to "intercept" the commands before they get executed and inject a comment with your unique id. Please see the following S.O. Answer for details. You shouldn't need the full extent of what they did, but even if you do, it seems like all of the code (or all the relevant stuff) is there:

[Adding a query hint when calling Table-Valued Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761827/adding-a-query-hint-when-calling-tvf/26762756#26762756)

By the way, this situation is a point in favor of using Stored Procedures instead of an ORM. And, what do you expect to be able to do in terms of performance tuning once you do find the offending app code? (another point in favor of using Stored Procedures instead of an ORM ;-).