# Transactional operation between multiple database

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

How can I use transactional operation between multiple database with Entity framework core ((2.1))? (Distributed Transaction)

```
try
{

    using (var tranScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (var ctx1 = new TestDBContext())
        using (var ctx2 = new TestDB2Context())
        {
            ctx1.Person.Add(new Person { Name = "piran" });

            ctx2.Course.Add(new Course { Name = "C#" });

            ctx1.SaveChanges();
            ctx2.SaveChanges();
        }

        tranScope.Complete();
    }

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

When running above code I give this exception:

> This platform does not support distributed transactions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF Core 2.0 TransactionScope Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577551/ef-core-2-0-transactionscope-error)

Comment: What's not clear about the exception message?

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your response , i want to know if  any solution exists for managing cross-database transaction in EF core ?